# strange mysql results in asp

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have the following piece of code:

```
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS anz FROM tbl_ergebnisse WHERE testavg >0"
set rs3 = Conn.Execute(strSQL)
Response.Write "Count(*): <br>" 
if not rs3.eof then
    Response.Write "Anz: " & rs3("anz")
else
    Response.Write "EOF" 
end if

strSQL = "SELECT testavg FROM tbl_ergebnisse WHERE testavg >0"
set rs2 = Conn.Execute(strSQL)

Response.Write "Entries: <br>" 
do while not rs2.eof
    Response.Write rs2("testavg") & "<br>"
rs2.MoveNext()
loop

strSQL = "SELECT AVG(testavg) AS mittelwert FROM tbl_ergebnisse WHERE testavg >0"
set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)

if not rs.eof then
    Response.Write "Mittelwert: " & rs("mittelwert")
else
    Response.Write "EOF" 
end if
```

Which give me a strange result:
Query 1 returns "4" (the count is correct). Query 2 returns no results and Query3 also returns no results

The table "tbl_ergebnisse" looks like this

```
testavg (DECIMAL)
```

with the entries: 3; 3; 4; 5;

Screenshot from data in the table can be found here: www.trinews.at/data.png

[image]

Any suggestions why I get an empty recordset? Running the querys direct on the database returns correct values.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you .close rs3  and rs2 before opening rs2 and rs respectively?

Comment: Which connector are you using?

Comment: Connecting through ODBC in Version 3.51

Comment: no, problem still exists. I also tried to change the sql statements, but also no change :-(

Comment: swap your first and last sql statements to see what happens? Maybe something magical might return? :-)

Comment: nothing magical happend, BUT, I changend "testavg" to "*" and then, the following error occours in asp error '80020009' (in the line, where I print out the result)

Comment: could there be a problem in ODBC with decimal values? shouldn't or?

Comment: can it be this bug? http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15556

Comment: sorry, i forgot: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

Comment: maybe cast the results as another type in your sql statement, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using CAST in your MySQL statement to convert the decimal type to a number that ASP ADODB can understand, otherwise ASP can't recognize the results from MySQL and thinks it's EOF. example:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(Entry_Data_1) as UNSIGNED) as score FROM contests_entries
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your issue with SQL Server Express with a field type of Decimal(18,0) and it worked as expected.

Try converting the results to doubles using CDbl as below.

```
strSQL = "SELECT testavg FROM tbl_ergebnisse WHERE testavg >0" 
set rs2 = Conn.Execute(strSQL)  
Response.Write "Entries: <br>"  
do while not rs2.eof     
    Response.Write CDbl(rs2("testavg")) & "<br>" 
rs2.MoveNext() 
loop  



strSQL = "SELECT AVG(testavg) AS mittelwert FROM tbl_ergebnisse WHERE testavg >0"
set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)  
if not rs.eof then     
    Response.Write "Mittelwert: " & CDbl(rs("mittelwert"))
else     
    Response.Write "EOF"  
end if
```

Comment: I am sorry, that didn't work. The reason is, that the resultset is eof, so the "else sector" is executed :-) 

very confusing ...

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of that mysql table and the data in it?

Comment: Here's the screenshot <img src="http://www.trinews.at/data.png">. 

I tried the types "integer", "decimal (10,5)", ...

Comment: I am sorry, I can't attach some image because I am new to stackoverflow. I added a link to the image. thx

Comment: I wonder is it something to do with you are executing queries on the mysql client but the changes are not fully committed but you can get results as you are in the same process which asp does not have access to. How about closing down the mysql client and reopening to ensure the changes have been committed and trying your web page again.

Comment: Did not help. Database is configured with phpmyadmin. Webpage is running on IIS. All data in the database is "really" stored. After shutdown and using phpmyadmin the data are here. But in the webpage the data are still not available :-(

Comment: Check your connection string? are you sure you are connected to right one?

Comment: yes, the connection string is correct. There is only one database.