# ASP Error: Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value. (Object Required)

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, vbscript

My old website in ASP started generating this error:

```
Microsoft Cursor Engine error '80040e21'
Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.
```

I haven't changed recently anything - perhaps my hosting provider made a change but the error is pointing to this line of code:

```
rs.Open SQL, adoCon
```

I checked: rs, adoCon and SQL are all set and it used to work for years before.

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
adoCon.Open  "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=<SERVER_NAME>; PORT=<PORT_NUMBER>;" &_
                    "DATABASE=<DBNAME>; USER=<USERNAME>; PASSWORD=<PASS>; OPTION=3;"
```

SQL is correct - I directly injected it into mySQL web interface and it generated needed results.

When I handle this error in ASP the Error.Description prints

```
"Object required"
```

What is it complaining about?

Comment: Did you check the connection state?

Comment: adoCon.State shows 1 which is adStateOpen

Comment: It looks I cannot telnet from outside. It's a hosting company so they may restrict this. But I do see that some database records are displayed on my page. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If at least some records from the database are shown in that page, the connection seems to be working, so the problem must lie somewhere else. I doubt anyone will be able to analyze the problem with just the 3 lines of code you posted. Also, have you checked the server logs?

Comment: I found it after 1 hr debugging - it's so weird. If I remove field name "Price" from my SQL query - everything starts working. I guarantee I was using this Price for years. What happened?

Comment: We wouldn't know, having no access to either your code or your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is that I had to convert decimal field to string. The fix looked like this:

```
SELECT Convert(Price,char) as Price FROM Table;
```

This is very strange but perhaps something was changed on my hosting provider site that caused this issue. I actually found similar solution here ([strange mysql results in asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846642/strange-mysql-results-in-asp)) which helped me to discover the issue. As I quote from link above "ASP can't recognize the results from MySQL and thinks it's EOF" without conversion from decimal to string.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened years ago With Oracle's Date/Time field having corrupt values causing this exact error when trying to select them.

Guess it's the same issue behind the scenes, what worked for me was manually deleting the corrupt rows using Oracle tools.

Another tip that has small chance to work is having such code instead:

```
adoCon.Open  "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=<SERVER_NAME>; PORT=<PORT_NUMBER>;" &_
                "DATABASE=<DBNAME>; USER=<USERNAME>; PASSWORD=<PASS>; OPTION=3;"
Set rs = adoCon.Execute(SQL)
```

Hopefully the cursor used in this method won't crash.

Comment: I tried but this error came up: Current Recordset does not support bookmarks. This may be a limitation of the provider or of the selected cursortype.

Comment: Perhaps I have corrupt Price. I will check for each value and update with status. Thanks

Comment: I found the answer. I had to convert decimal field to string. The fix looked like SELECT Convert(Price,char) as Price FROM Table;

Comment: @Vad weird, but classic ASP do have its dark and weird side. Please post this as answer so others will benefit from it, leaving this answer as well as another possibility. :)